# How to break the if condition?

Tags: java

```
package com.selenium.utitlity;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ReadRows {
    public static Hashtable<String, String> getRowValues(int row)
            throws IOException {
        File file = new File("./prop.xlsx");
        if (file.exists()) {
            Hashtable<String, String> table = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook("./prop.xlsx");
            XSSFSheet sourceSheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
            int LastRow = sourceSheet.getLastRowNum();
            // GetHeading of the Row
            XSSFRow headerRow = sourceSheet.getRow(0);
            // Get Test Data
            XSSFRow sourceRow = sourceSheet.getRow(row);
            if (row > LastRow) {
                System.out.println("The row is out of range");
            } else {
                int lastColumn = headerRow.getLastCellNum();
                for (int i = 0; i < lastColumn; i++) {
                    table.put(headerRow.getCell(i).toString(), sourceRow
                            .getCell(i).toString());
                }
            }
            return table;
        } else {
            System.out.println("No such file is there in the directory");
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

I am trying to use break or exit in the following piece of code:

```
if (row > LastRow) {
                    System.out.println("The row is out of range");
                }
```

to exit the code not to return table as NULL. But if break is not used i am getting following result

```
The row is out of range
null
```

I dont want to print null i wanted to use break when row > LastRow

Comment: remove the else part and you should get table populated.

Comment: You can't use `break` here, and even if you could, this would not solve the problem what to return. I'd suggest that you `throw` some sort of Exception, e.g. `IllegalArgumentException`, in this case.

Comment: convert the outer `if` into an loop-able construct `for`/`while` that runs once (e.g. `break` at the end) and then you can break it inside an if statement.

Comment: you can use `goto` though its deprecated but might be help ful to you.

Comment: The output `null` is not coming from this method. Probably from the method that calls it. Can you add that method to your question (use the *edit* link)?

Comment: @BhargavModi There is no `goto` in Java, nor has there ever been (except at the early development stages).

Answer (score 1):

First I'd like to point out that `if` statements are not loops. They may be used recursively but that's out of their natural use. In order to break or continue loops you may simple use the `break` or `continue` keyword.

These are used both in labelled and unlabelled contexts. Check out [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) for a more in-depth explanation.

`break` is used to terminate `for`, `while` & `do-while` however not usable in your context. You should `throw` an Exception instead. You can then catch the exception and do whatever you wish to do with it.

You may however use both `break` and `continue` in an `if` statement when it's inside a loop.

Hope this helps.